# Revise from repository on standalone Win7?

Tags: qgis

I'd like to fix the bug in QGIS whereby starting QGIS offline or on a slow connection can kill it, using this revision: http://hub.qgis.org/projects/quantum-gis/repository/revisions/bb623a8c94e49ed478f736a58df49732edd338b4

Problem is, I installed from the standalone installer, not OSGEO4W. What's the best way to go about this, and possible future repository-based installs? Save my files, uninstall QGIS & start again from OSGEO4W?

Answer (score 2):

With OSGeo4w, you can install the latest Qgis dev build (currently 1.9.0 master). It can be installed in parallel to the standalone or OSGEO4W stable version. If you want that specific revision, you have to compile it yourself.

Be sure to use the current osgeo4w-setup.exe, older ones have a bug that crashes the installation.